# meaning of divine in the context

Tags: meaning

In Book 6 - Lecture 6 - 1189 of [Aristotle's Ethics](https://isidore.co/aquinas/Ethics6.htm#6), it says:

> That man is the most excellent of all animals makes no difference, because there are other creatures more divine by their nature, for instance, the very evident things that constitute the universe.

It states that:

- man is the most excellent of all animals;
- there are other creatures more divine by their nature than man, such as the things [heavenly bodies] constituting the universe.

How do I understand the word *divine*?

If it means Godlike, men are created in God's images, there should be no other things more divine than men;

I found in [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/divine) the definition of "being a deity", and deity could mean "one exalted or revered as supremely good or powerful". The sun or black holes are more powerful than men in many aspects.

I just try to understand the text better. What's your thought on the word *divine* in this context?

Comment: Aristotle wrote in ancient Greek, not English. I'm sure the translator chose the word **divine** for a good reason, but I do not recommend exploring its subtleties for a deeper insight into Aristotle's intended meaning.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138410/discussion-on-question-by-h-li-meaning-of-divine-in-the-context).

Answer (score 1):

It's another way of saying **superior to**, however you want to understand it.

Whether humans are created in God's image is a matter of religious belief, not of English grammar.

Comment: And of course he was neither a Jew nor a Christian.